# error invalid allocation size while debugging my code

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, runtime-error

i was implementing a code given in schaum's book programming with c++,and i got this debugging error "***invalid allocation bytes 446578765(number like this)***" . i am learning c++ can someone help why this error is coming up??

`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(unsigned arg=8):size(arg),data(new T[arg]){}  // constructor
    Vector(const Vector<T> &v ):size(v.size),data(new T[size]) // copy constructor
        {
      copy(v);
    }
    ~Vector(){delete [] data;}//destructor
    Vector <T>& operator = (const Vector<T>&); // assignment operator
    T& operator [] (unsigned i) const { return data[i];}
    unsigned _size()
    {
      return size;
    }

private:
    T* data;
    unsigned size;
    void copy(const Vector<T> &);

};

template<class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector<T> & v)
{
    size = v.size;
    data = new T[size];
    copy(v);
    return *this;

}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::copy(const Vector<T> &v)
{
    int min_size=(size<v.size?size:v.size);

    for(short int i=0;i<min_size;i++)
    {
        data[i]=v.data[i];
    }
}


int main()
{
  Vector<int> obj;

  obj[2]=27;

  Vector<int> w=obj,x;
  cout<<w._size();
}
```

`

Comment: i checked the error by using break feature in visual studio and figured out that something happened to heap while allocating memory using new operator......

Comment: Should you not be using `v.size` in `new T[size]`?

Comment: can u b more specific as i am new to c++ programming..

Comment: Your `operator=` is leaking. You save a pointer to the new buffer in `this->data`, and thus lose the pointer to the old buffer, which is never deallocated. This is not the cause of your immediate problem though, as your program doesn't actually call `operator=`.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor initializes data members in the order they are listed in the class definition - **not** in the order they are listed in the constructor initializer list. Case in point:

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(const Vector<T> &v ):size(v.size),data(new T[size]) {...}
private:
    T* data;
    unsigned size;
};
```

The initializer list would suggest that `size` is initialized to `v.size` first, and then `new T[size]` is executed using the value of `size` that was just set.

But that's not what happens. In reality, since `data` is listed ahead of `size` in the class definition, `new T[size]` is executed first - and at that point, `size` is still uninitialized, containing random garbage. This code exhibits undefined behavior.

Make it

```
    Vector(const Vector<T> &v ):data(new T[v.size]), size(v.size) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You mentioned _since data is listed ahead of size in the class definition, new T[size] is executed first_. Is it mentioned in C++ standard?

Comment: **12.6.2/10** In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order: ... then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
(again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*)...